# Range of first and last character in the string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a string as per below:

```
$ab$c x$yz$
```

The string would always start with $ and would end with a $ character. I wish to find the range of the start $ and end $.

I tried: `NSRange range = [myStr rangeOfString:@"$"];`

I get the output as `(NSRange) $0 = location=0` for its location so I am assuming that it is just returning the range of first '$' found in the string.

How do I get range of start $ and end $?

What I am exactly trying to do here is I am using the below method:

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

So when I type text as '$' I wish to check if '$' is in between start '$' and end '$'. So I am finding it out using the range. If range of '$' I type is between the range of start '$' and end '$' then do this, else do that.

Comment: Us regular expressions.  I'm not good at using them so I have no advice, but I know it's possible with them.  Hopefully someone with experience will come along and give you code for that, otherwise search for regular expressions.

Comment: Your example is a little unclear.  With your example what would is the desired outcome?  (what ranges would you expect to recieve?)

Comment: With regards to regular expressions: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Comment: I just updated my question with what exactly I am trying to do by finding the ranges.

Comment: RTFM: "rangeOfString:options:range:

Finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string, within the given range of the receiver, subject to given options."

Comment: The range of the start `$` will always be `0,1` and the range of the end `$` will always be `string.length-1,1`. If you just want to know if the string has the start and end `$` then use `hasPrefix:` and `hasSuffix:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option for backward search (`NSBackwardsSearch`). here you can find the correct range of string:

```
 NSRange rangeFirst = [myStr rangeOfString:@"$"],rangeLast=[myStr rangeOfString:@"$" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
```

Comment: But that won't isolate the first string in his example (where there are two).

Answer (score 2):

I think, what you want is a function like this:

```
-(BOOL) isRange:(NSRange)range includedIn:(NSString*)fullText {
    //Init fullTextRange
    NSRange fullTextRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0);

    if ([fullText hasPrefix:@"$"] && [fullText hasSuffix:@"$"]) {
        //We have a range of start$ and end$
        fullTextRange.length = [fullText length] - 1;
    }

    //Check if range is included in fullTextRange
    return (NSIntersectionRange(range, fullTextRange).length == range.length);
}
```

It returns *YES* when the range of the text is between start'$' and end'$'.

You should then use it like this:

```
 - (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if ([self isRange:range includedIn:searchBar.text]) {
        //Do something
    }
    else {
        //Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: That method has quite a bad name. Better (i.e. much more readable) is '+(BOOL)isRange:(NSRange)range includedIn:(NSString *)fullText'. But then, this method looks overly complicated and hard to understand.

Comment: I agree about the method name, it was an oversight. First I though the solution was stupid simple but then I realized there are some tricky cases. What exactly looks complicated to you?

Comment: The logic hides very well... fullTextRange is created and conditionally changed, and then some (the main!) "magic" logic is applied in the return statement. That code is just too "clever". Put it away for a month, have another look at it and try to tell what it does (without looking at bigger context).

Comment: Ok. I tried to explain a bit the "magic" using comments... In this particular case I think context is very important as it is not a common use case. Anyways, thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is deciding if the text the user is changing does not contain the first or last character (because as you said, the first and last char will always be a '$') this is quite easy.

```
if(range.location==0)
  return NO; //first $
if(range.location + range.length == text.length - 1)
  return NO; //last $

//Do whatever in the case you want to allow the edit.
```

Comment: I have. He says "the string would always start and end with $... How do I get range of start $ and end $".

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  It is very poorly worded, I read it very different than you did.  I assumed he know the start and finish locations but wanted the locations of $ inside the overall string, but question taken literally you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

- NSRange rangeOfRest = NSRangeMake for 1 past first `$` to end of string
- NSRange secondDollar = [myStr rangeOfString:@"$" options:0 range:rangeOfRest];